# Should chemical names in figures be capitalised?

Tags: terminology

If I draw a molecule (for example glucose) and I want to name it, should I write glucose or Glucose? My aim is to draw a molecule, add the name below and then use this as a figure in a Word text.

Comment: It's really up to you. I usually stick with uncapitalised.

Comment: If you do this with the automatic function in ChemDraw ("Convert Structure to Name"), the label is not capitalized.

Comment: Treat chemical names as common nouns with uniform style. However, due to verbosity of certain chemical names, it might be a good idea to label each chemical structure with unique number and provide corresponding names in text. This is likely going to save a lot of hassle if you are asked to use PINs or fit your images into a column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stay with the rules set by IUPAC's colour books, e.g. [Blue Book](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/ebook/9780854041824) for organic compounds, and [Red Book](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/ebook/978-0-85404-438-2) for inorganic compound, and  and ***don't capitalize the names*** if these names are used within an English phrase.  Descriptors like (*E*/*Z*) you always capitalize are a different thing, though.

If these documents are too long for you, you may consider their condensed versions (cf. chemistry.se [resources page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry/155812#155812) about material to learn chemistry, section nomenclature) for their brief guide and 4-page excerpts ([guide](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/pac-2019-0104/html), [excerpt](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/pac-2019-0104/downloadAsset/suppl/j_pac-2019-0104_suppl.pdf) for organic; [guide](https://doi.org/10.1515/pac-2014-0718), [excerpt](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Silverbook_concise-summary2017.pdf) for inorganic compounds).  Below the heading of the 4-page excerpts for both (which are published *open access*):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Both the brief guides, as well as the 4-page excerpts include flow charts how to determine the elements to consider (e.g., what are elements/substitutents; their number), how to name them, and how to sort them by priority. I still consider these and their intentional use of colour very helpful.